# How to create a table of a user?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I create a table of a user with sys? I want to give a table to an user but I want that this user can't alter the table.

I tried this:

```
CONNECT USER1/USER1;
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

But I want to create this table from sys user so user1 can't alter this table. How can I do that?

Comment: You create this table as `USER1`, but you don't want `USER1` to be able to alter it? I don't get it.

Comment: Why not just create a new schema that can own the table, then grant the necessary privileges on that table to your other user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USER1 can `alter` a table in their schema, even if they don't have CREATE TABLE privilege.

As SYS:

```
grant create session to user1;

alter user user1 quota 100M on users ;

create table user1.t1 (id number);
```

Now connect as USER1. Both these statements will succeed:

```
insert into t1 values (1234);

alter table t1 add col1 varchar2(16);
```

In case it's not clear, USER1 cannot create tables. This statement will fail with `ORA-01031: insufficient privileges`...

```
create table t2(id number);
```

---

It's not clear exactly what you're trying to achieve, but the best way to control schemas is to separate schema owners from application users. Schema owners have objects but (usually) lack CREATE SESSION privilege, at least in production: their objects are deployed by power user accounts. Application users have CREATE SESSION and DML privileges on objects in the schema owner accounts but don't own any objects themselves, except maybe private synonyms and database links.